# VizFrame column chart with longer dimension

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to implement a column chart, which lists data for many years.. If I choose an year for column chart, it displays data for 12 months (12 bars for each month). If I choose 10 years, then it ends up in showing

10*12 = 120 columns in chart.

To overcome this, I am looking for a column chart which would show dotted line between long ranges.

That is: if user chooses 10 years data from 2000 to 2010, I have to display first and last 5 months data as vertical bar [Jan-May data of 2000 (5 column bars), Aug-Dec data of 2010 (5 column bars)] and a dotted vertical line or some characters to indicate the data is not displayed between these ranges.

Horizontal scroll is an option for which I have seen some examples. However, my requirement is as mentioned above without scrollbar.. Which vizChart type can be used for this purpose? Can someone please provide more details..

Regards,

SAP Learner

Comment: If you set the values of the columns in the middle to zero (Value=0) you might get this effect.
But I’m wondering about the informational value you get out of such a chart, where most of the data is just not displayed.
Maybe you might want to have a look at vizchart feature [Range Selector](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.viz.sample.RangeSlider/preview). There you can drill down into smaller timeframes.
You might also want to look at the vizchart feature “Break Missing Value” as seen in [Time Axis](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.viz.sample.TimeConfig/preview)

Comment: Another option might be to use combined charts, as seen [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.viz.sample.TimeAxis/preview)
and [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.viz.sample.CombinedColumnLine/preview).